# Django rest-auth password reset not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django for building a RESTful API for a mobile app, I use django rest-auth library for authentication, but I get the following error when I try using password reset:

```
NoReverseMatch at /auth/password/reset/
Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_confirm' with arguments '(b'OQ', '4nx-
6653c24101b5443f726b')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) 
tried: []
```

Given this snippet from my url patterns

```
url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r'^auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

I tried some solutions mentioned here (as adding this first pattern in the snippet) but still having the same error.

Comment: are the other endpoints working? Can you please give more details about the request you are making, like it is a POST and some sample data?

Comment: Try commenting out the first url, it may be catching them all. If it does not help, post more about how your are accessing the URL

Comment: @FBidu yes the whole API is working well, and the login and registration are also working.I post the payload listed in the doc of the rest-auth lib(in case of password reset, just the email address)

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I already added it as it was mentioned as a working solution, but also without it, it's still not working. I access it with simple POST requests either from the app or Postman with the email in the payload only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :
In **Settings.py** : Make sure 'app' is at the end of installed apps

then try again

Comment: which app should be at the end of the installed app?

Comment: downvoting the answer, which app and why?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have that url defined, you can check the demo project from rest-auth library to see how it handles the urls (and related templates).

https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/demo/demo/urls.py

Answer (score 0):

This error means you have not defined any url with this name `auth_password_reset_confirm` so you need to make a url with this name `auth_password_reset_confirm`.

You need to customize the `django rest-auth` in such a way.

> In rest-auth > urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
    ....
]
```

See in this case, you put the `name` as `auth_password_reset_confirm`. In my case, I got this error for this reverse url `password_reset_confirm` so I put that as a name in urls.

**But in your case it would be `auth_password_reset_confirm`.**